# Get Listbox properties from ListBoxItem datatemplate

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

Is there a way to bind a property of the listboxitem to one of it's owning listbox? I want it in a template so I believe that rules out ElementName.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `FindAncestor` mode of the `Binding` class. Like this:

`{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}, Path=YourProperty}`